# How do I recover LXDE on my system?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, lxde

Recently I was playing around with LXDE on Debian, customizing the panel, and so...

But after I installed obkey and logged out and logged in to use it, LXDE didn't load anymore. GNOME works fine.

For example, when I try to start it from a TTY, I get the following message:

```
(lxsession:5261): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display
```

When I execute `export DISPLAY=:0.0 ; startlxde` I no longer get the GTK warning message and all I get is:

```
** Message: main.vala:99: Session is LXDE
** Message: main.vala:100: DE is LXDE
** Message: main.vala:131: log directory: /home/victorh18/.cache/lxsession/LXDE
** Message: main.vala:132: log path: /home/victorh18/.cache/lxsession/LXDE/run.log
```

I've tried purging LXDE from my system by executing: `apt-get purge lxde lxde-core lxsession....`, but after reinstalling it, the problem persisted.

I would like to know what can I do to "reset" LXDE to its original form, because I'm really curious about tinkering it without having to reinstall Debian again, which is all I can think I can do to solve the problem.

This is the run.log file:

```
** Message: environement.vala:58: Exporting primary_variable
** Message: environement.vala:59: desktop_environnement XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP
** Message: environement.vala:149: confir_dirs is null, export : /etc/xdg
** Message: environement.vala:183: Exporting XDG_CONFIG_DIRS
** Message: environement.vala:217: custom_data :/usr/local/share:/usr/share:/usr/share/gdm:/var/lib/menu-xdg:
** Message: environement.vala:218: data_dirs :/usr/local/share/:/usr/share/:/usr/share/gdm/:/var/lib/menu-xdg/
** Message: environement.vala:219: data_dirs not null, export : /usr/local/share:/usr/share:/usr/share/gdm:/var/lib/menu-xdg:/usr/local/share/:/usr/share/:/usr/share/gdm/:/var/lib/menu-xdg/
** Message: environement.vala:224: Exporting XDG_DATA_DIRS
** Message: utils.vala:68: User config used : /home/victorh18/.config/lxsession/LXDE/desktop.conf
** Message: utils.vala:89: Final file used : /home/victorh18/.config/lxsession/LXDE/desktop.conf
** Message: settings.vala:527: El archivo de claves no tiene la clave «iGtk/ColorScheme»
** Message: settings.vala:527: El archivo de claves no tiene la clave «windows_manager/extras»
** Message: settings.vala:527: El archivo de claves no tiene la clave «panel/command»
** Message: settings.vala:527: El archivo de claves no tiene la clave «dock/command»
** Message: settings.vala:527: El archivo de claves no tiene la clave «file_manager/command»
** Message: settings.vala:527: El archivo de claves no tiene la clave «desktop_manager/command»
** Message: settings.vala:527: El archivo de claves no tiene la clave «launcher_manager/autostart»
** Message: settings.vala:527: El archivo de claves no tiene la clave «composite_manager/command»
** Message: settings.vala:527: El archivo de claves no tiene la clave «im1/command»
** Message: settings.vala:527: El archivo de claves no tiene la clave «im2/command»
** Message: settings.vala:527: El archivo de claves no tiene la clave «widget1/command»
** Message: settings.vala:527: El archivo de claves no tiene la clave «notification/command»
** Message: settings.vala:527: El archivo de claves no tiene la clave «keybindings/command»
** Message: settings.vala:527: El archivo de claves no tiene la clave «screensaver/command»
** Message: settings.vala:527: El archivo de claves no tiene la clave «power_manager/command»
** Message: settings.vala:527: El archivo de claves no tiene la clave «audio_manager/command»
** Message: settings.vala:527: El archivo de claves no tiene la clave «workspace_manager/command»
** Message: settings.vala:527: El archivo de claves no tiene la clave «screenshot_manager/command»
** Message: settings.vala:527: El archivo de claves no tiene la clave «message_manager/command»
** Message: settings.vala:527: El archivo de claves no tiene la clave «upgrade_manager/command»
** Message: settings.vala:527: El archivo de claves no tiene la clave «upstart_user_session»
** Message: settings.vala:527: El archivo de claves no tiene la clave «proxy_manager/http»
** Message: settings.vala:527: El archivo de claves no tiene la clave «a11y/command»
** Message: settings.vala:527: El archivo de claves no tiene la clave «xrandr/command»
** Message: settings.vala:527: El archivo de claves no tiene la clave «network_gui/command»
** Message: settings.vala:527: El archivo de claves no tiene la clave «webbrowser/command»
** Message: settings.vala:527: El archivo de claves no tiene la clave «email/command»
** Message: settings.vala:527: El archivo de claves no tiene la clave «pdf_reader/command»
** Message: settings.vala:527: El archivo de claves no tiene la clave «video_player/command»
** Message: settings.vala:527: El archivo de claves no tiene la clave «audio_player/command»
** Message: settings.vala:527: El archivo de claves no tiene la clave «images_display/command»
** Message: settings.vala:527: El archivo de claves no tiene la clave «text_editor/command»
** Message: settings.vala:527: El archivo de claves no tiene la clave «archive/command»
** Message: settings.vala:527: El archivo de claves no tiene la clave «charmap/command»
** Message: settings.vala:527: El archivo de claves no tiene la clave «calculator/command»
** Message: settings.vala:527: El archivo de claves no tiene la clave «spreadsheet/command»
** Message: settings.vala:527: El archivo de claves no tiene la clave «bittorent/command»
** Message: settings.vala:527: El archivo de claves no tiene la clave «document/command»
** Message: settings.vala:527: El archivo de claves no tiene la clave «webcam/command»
** Message: settings.vala:527: El archivo de claves no tiene la clave «burn/command»
** Message: settings.vala:527: El archivo de claves no tiene la clave «notes/command»
** Message: settings.vala:527: El archivo de claves no tiene la clave «disk_utility/command»
** Message: settings.vala:527: El archivo de claves no tiene la clave «tasks/command»
** Message: settings.vala:527: El archivo de claves no tiene el grupo «Keymap»
** Message: settings.vala:527: El archivo de claves no tiene la clave «laptop_mode»
** Message: settings.vala:527: El archivo de claves no tiene la clave «gnome»
** Message: settings.vala:527: El archivo de claves no tiene el grupo «Updates»
** Message: settings.vala:527: El archivo de claves no tiene la clave «type»
** Message: settings.vala:449: Monitoring: /home/victorh18/.config/lxsession/LXDE/desktop.conf
** Message: settings.vala:453: Desktop file is already in config home, do nothing
** Message: environement.vala:79: Exporting variable
** Message: environement.vala:80: desktop_environnement XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP
** Message: environement.vala:176: custom_config :
** Message: environement.vala:177: config_dirs :/etc/xdg
** Message: environement.vala:178: confir_dirs not null, export : /etc/xdg
** Message: environement.vala:183: Exporting XDG_CONFIG_DIRS
** Message: environement.vala:217: custom_data :
** Message: environement.vala:218: data_dirs :/usr/local/share:/usr/share:/usr/share/gdm:/var/lib/menu-xdg:/usr/local/share/:/usr/share/:/usr/share/gdm/:/var/lib/menu-xdg/
** Message: environement.vala:219: data_dirs not null, export : /usr/local/share:/usr/share:/usr/share/gdm:/var/lib/menu-xdg:/usr/local/share/:/usr/share/:/usr/share/gdm/:/var/lib/menu-xdg/
** Message: environement.vala:224: Exporting XDG_DATA_DIRS
** Message: utils.vala:79: Config system location : /etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE
** Message: utils.vala:85: System system path location : /etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE/conffiles.conf
** Message: utils.vala:89: Final file used : /etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE/conffiles.conf
** Message: options.vala:164: Activate xsettings_manager build-in
** Message: utils.vala:68: User config used : /home/victorh18/.config/lxsession/LXDE/desktop.conf
** Message: utils.vala:89: Final file used : /home/victorh18/.config/lxsession/LXDE/desktop.conf
** Message: app.vala:717: polkit separate
** Message: app.vala:717: polkit separate
** Message: app.vala:76: Launching lxpolkit 
** Message: utils.vala:68: User config used : /home/victorh18/.config/lxsession/LXDE/autostart
** Message: utils.vala:89: Final file used : /home/victorh18/.config/lxsession/LXDE/autostart
** Message: autostart.vala:42: Autostart path : /home/victorh18/.config/lxsession/LXDE/autostart
** Message: app.vala:76: Launching lxpanel 
** Message: app.vala:76: Launching pcmanfm 
** Message: app.vala:76: Launching xscreensaver 
** Message: options.vala:107: Create build-in Clipboard
Another clipboard manager is already running.** Message: main.vala:429: Check keymap_mode (null)
** Message: app.vala:76: Launching /usr/bin/ssh-agent 
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/ssh-eFolN3dTAfGa/agent.2832; export SSH_AUTH_SOCK;
SSH_AGENT_PID=2843; export SSH_AGENT_PID;
echo Agent pid 2843;
** Message: x-terminal-emulator has very limited support, consider choose another terminal
```

After this, the command halts and I get no more progress

Thanks in advice

Comment: Have you tried purging obkey and seeing if that solves the issue?

Comment: Yes, I purged obkey from my system.